# Perl's 2D hash initialization - do we have any faster way?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hash, initialization

I am looking for a fast 2D hash initialization. I know some recommended use undef, but I need it to be 1. I have tested 4 different flavors as below (please ignore the naming, as I am bad at names)
Surprisingly, for_2d_init_array has the fastest execution.

But, i am still not satisfy with it, as when the $limit=4000, it requires roughly 4-5s for complete initialization. Is there any faster way to do so?

I know there is a bit-vector for such application. For now, I would like to maintain such structure.

```
timethese(-2, {
       for_2d_original => sub {
                                my %hash;
                                my $limit = 100;
                                for(my $i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                        for(my $j=0; $j<$limit; $j++){
                                $hash{$i}{$j}=1;
                                }
                                }
                           },
       for_2d_map => sub {
                                my %hash;
                                my $limit = 100;
                                for(my $i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                                        $hash{$i} = {map { $_ => 1 } 0..$limit-1};
                                }
                           },
       for_2d_init_hash => sub {
                                my %hash;
                                my $limit = 100;
                                for(my $i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                                        my %tmp_hash;
                                        for(my $j=0; $j<$limit; $j++){
                                                $tmp_hash{$j} = 1;
                                        }
                                        $hash{$i} = \%tmp_hash;
                                }
                           },
       for_2d_init_hash_w_array => sub {
                                my %hash;
                                my $limit = 100;
                                my @array = (0..$limit-1);
                                my @init = (1)x$limit;
                                for(my $i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                                        my %tmp_hash;
                                        @tmp_hash{@array} = @init;
                                        $hash{$i} = \%tmp_hash;
                                }
                           },
});
```

**Results:**
for_2d_original:  3 wallclock secs ( 2.10 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.10 CPU) @ 751.90/s (n=1579)
for_2d_map:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.18 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.18 CPU) @ 559.17/s (n=1219)
for_2d_init_hash:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.15 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.15 CPU) @ 994.42/s (n=2138)
for_2d_init_hash_w_array:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.12 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.12 CPU) @ 1580.19/s (n=3350)

Comment: Why use a hash when you need each and every matrix element?

Comment: "legacy" as implied by my last sentence. It is built using such structure. I am trying to improves its initialization. 
When you mention matrix, is it 2D array execute faster?

Comment: Any strong reason to do initialization at all?

Comment: Perhaps freezing structure and thawing with some module.

Comment: What is this actually for?  How are all those keys generated, what do they represent?  Hashes are slow, and you need a lot of access (4k^2), with intermediate structures/variables created.  Can improve things somewhat (`for my $i (0..$limit-1)` instead of that C-style loop) but it'll still take time.  (Btw, all second-level hashes you show are the same -- I presume that that's not the case in reality?)

Comment: Yes, @zdim. they are all the same except execution speed.

Comment: probably it's the limit of hash. I take a hint from Armali and change it to 2D array instead. It works great.

Results
for_2d_init_array:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.13 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.13 CPU) @ 308376.06/s (n=656841)
timethese(-2, {
      for_2d_init_array => sub {
                                my %hash;
                                my $limit = 100;
                                my @init = ([(1)x$limit], [(1)x$limit]);
                           },
});

Comment: Are you aware that with this _for_2d_init_array_ not a $limit × $limit, but only a 2 × $limit matrix is created?

Comment: @Armali yes, jhnc pointed out in my answer below. i have changed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a hint from Armali and replace with 2D array and the results is great. I know this is no longer a 2D hash, I consider this structure as fine, as I can just replace {} to [] for the remaining of the legacy code the system have. Thanks all. (initially, it is a variable sizes of hash in each rows. ) For completeness, I included the code and its results.

```
timethese(-2, {
   for_2d_original => sub {
                            my %hash;
                            my $limit = 100;
                            for(my $i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                    for(my $j=0; $j<$limit; $j++){
                            $hash{$i}{$j}=1;
                            }
                            }
                       },
   for_2d_map => sub {
                            my %hash;
                            my $limit = 100;
                            for(my $i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                                    $hash{$i} = {map { $_ => 1 } 0..$limit-1};
                            }
                       },
   for_2d_init_hash => sub {
                            my %hash;
                            my $limit = 100;
                            for(my $i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                                    my %tmp_hash;
                                    for(my $j=0; $j<$limit; $j++){
                                            $tmp_hash{$j} = 1;
                                    }
                                    $hash{$i} = \%tmp_hash;
                            }
                       },
   for_2d_init_hash_w_array => sub {
                            my %hash;
                            my $limit = 100;
                            my @array = (0..$limit-1);
                            my @init = (1)x$limit;
                            for(my $i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                                    my %tmp_hash;
                                    @tmp_hash{@array} = @init;
                                    $hash{$i} = \%tmp_hash;
                            }
                       },
   for_2d_init_array => sub {
                            my $limit = 100;
                            my @init;
                            $init[$_] = [(1)x$limit] for 0..$limit-1;
                       }, 
});
```

**Results:**

```
for_2d_original:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.12 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.12 CPU) @ 744.81/s (n=1579)
for_2d_map:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.19 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.19 CPU) @ 556.62/s (n=1219)
for_2d_init_hash:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.21 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.21 CPU) @ 978.28/s (n=2162)
for_2d_init_hash_w_array:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.15 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.15 CPU) @ 1558.14/s (n=3350)
for_2d_init_array:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.10 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.10 CPU) @ 6018.57/s (n=12639)
```

Comment: `for_2d_init_array` only generates 100*2 elements. Don't you want 100*100 ?

Comment: `my @init; $init[$_] = [(1)x$limit] for 0..$limit-1;` ?

Comment: Thanks @jhnc, I am over-excited to implement it and copy/paste my small testcase wrongly. I have updated it. Appreciate it very much.